# CSS Positions: Img to right middle of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div element in my page, and an arrow, that I am trying to get to the right middle of the div. Here's the code:
HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
   <p>
      This is the inside of a div element.
   </p>
</div>
<div id="image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {  
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-top:100px;
}
#image {
    background-image:url('/images/jquerys penis.png');
    border:1px solid black;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
}
```

Website that I'm working on: [site.brycemckenney.com/jquery.html](http://site.brycemckenney.com/jquery.html)

Comment: Before you can use CSS reliably, you must use a proper doctype declaration, namely '<!doctype html>'; more info here: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: Please try to be a little more mature when naming your images.

Comment: I think it's fittingly named. :p

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify your markup a little: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/y7jTb/

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
    <p>This is the inside of a div element.</p>
    <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {  
    width: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto; }
#popup * { white-space: normal; }
#popup p { 
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#image {
    background: url('http://site.brycemckenney.com/images/jquerys%20penis.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }​
```

This solution depends on `display: inline-block;`, `white-space: nowrap`, and `vertical-align: middle;`. If you need help understanding any of what I've just posted, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Would probably use absolute positioning myself, but I'm not entirely certain what the little image is for.

Answer (score -1):

On #image style add:

```
width: 30px;
margin: auto;
```